# Unable to access JDI classes in Eclipse project

Tags: java, eclipse, jdi

I wanted to try writing my own Debugger but was not able to do so yet as I cannot get Eclipse to allow me to programmatically access any classes of the Java Debug Interface (JDI). At first, I thought I may have a problem with my installed JDK (`JDK 15.0.2`) but a test with a manually compiled and executed file which featured some code for launching a Java-VM in debug mode showed that the installation is fine, and the problem must have something to do with Eclipse. If I navigate to the `jdk.jdi` JAR located in the JRE System Library submenu of the package explorer of my project I can even see all of the classes I would need (`LaunchingConnector, Bootstrap, MethodEntryRequest, etc.`). I recreated the project a few times already and also tinkered with some Build Path settings but to no avail. I'm kind of lost as to what I should try next, so any help is much appreciated.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to @nitind for providing the answer. I simply had to remove the check mark for `com.sun.*` in the **Type Filters** preference page, then everything worked like a charm.

Comment: Check your **Type Filters** preference page.

Comment: That was it, thank you very much.